# No output of some tag XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How can i output the value of `NUMBER` for every `GRP/ADD/CONTACT` where QUALIFIER = EM?

Correct output should be: `test@test.de`. Please find my XML and XSLT attached:

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TEST>
  <CNT>
    <GRP>
      <ADD>
        <QUALIFIER>DP</QUALIFIER>
        <PARTY_NAME_1>Vorname Nachname</PARTY_NAME_1>
        <STREET_1>Strasse 1</STREET_1>
        <CITY>Ort</CITY>
        <POSTAL_CODE>12345</POSTAL_CODE>
        <COUNTRY_CODE>DE</COUNTRY_CODE>
        <CONTACT>
          <QUALIFIER>TE</QUALIFIER>
          <NUMBER>4657</NUMBER>
        </CONTACT>
        <CONTACT>
          <QUALIFIER>EM</QUALIFIER>
          <NUMBER>test2@test.de</NUMBER>
        </CONTACT>
      </ADD>
      <ADD>
        <QUALIFIER>ST</QUALIFIER>
        <PARTY_NAME_1>Vorname Nachname</PARTY_NAME_1>
        <STREET_1>Strasse 1</STREET_1>
        <CITY>Ort</CITY>
        <POSTAL_CODE>12345</POSTAL_CODE>
        <COUNTRY_CODE>DE</COUNTRY_CODE>
        <CONTACT>
          <QUALIFIER>TE</QUALIFIER>
          <NUMBER>12345</NUMBER>
        </CONTACT>
        <CONTACT>
          <QUALIFIER>EM</QUALIFIER>
          <NUMBER>test@test.de</NUMBER>
        </CONTACT>
      </ADD>
    </GRP>
  </CNT>
</TEST>
```

XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GRP">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select ="./ADD/CONTACT[QUALIFIER='ST']">
          <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='EM'">
            <CONTACT_EMAIL>
              <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>
            </CONTACT_EMAIL>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--copy all other nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- delete empty nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
    <!-- delete empty nodes -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also tried this:

`<xsl:for-each select ="./ADD/CONTACT">` instead of `<xsl:for-each select ="./ADD/CONTACT[QUALIFIER='ST']">`, but there i get all data of the value "number" (from qualifier DP and ST) but i need just from qualifier ST.

Comment: Your question is self-contradicting. In the first sentence you say you need qualifier EM, in the last sentence you say you need qualifier ST.

Comment: hi, no there are to differents at ADD. 1x. ADD where qualifier is ST and the second qualifier is behind add.

so: add/qualifier(dp)/contact/qualifier(TE/EM)
     add/qualifier(st)/contact/qualifier(TE/EM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the result you want, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select ="ADD[QUALIFIER='ST']/CONTACT[QUALIFIER='EM']">
            <CONTACT_EMAIL>
                <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>
            </CONTACT_EMAIL>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--copy all other nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the identity template (`<xsl:template match="@* | node()">`) twice in your XSLT, you can remove the second one.

That being said, your logic goes like this

```
<xsl:for-each select ="./ADD/CONTACT[QUALIFIER='ST']">
  <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='EM'">
    <CONTACT_EMAIL>
      <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>
    </CONTACT_EMAIL>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This cannot work. Judging from your example XML, there can't be a `<CONTACT>` with qualifier equal to `ST` that **also** has a qualifier equal to `EM`.

You probably mean this:

```
<xsl:for-each select ="ADD/CONTACT[QUALIFIER='EM']">
  <CONTACT_EMAIL>
    <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>
  </CONTACT_EMAIL>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Notes

- I'm not sure that your "copy all other nodes" call to `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />` is what you want. I'd say it's not.
- Writing `./` is redundant in XPath. Every path that does not start at the root of the document is relative to the current node by default anyway.

Comment: thanks, but with your code i get both value of add/contact with qualifier EM
<CONTACT_EMAIL>test2@test.de</CONTACT_EMAIL>
<CONTACT_EMAIL>test@test.de</CONTACT_EMAIL>

for me it´s important just to get <CONTACT_EMAIL>test@test.de</CONTACT_EMAIL> not both

Comment: Well, filter for `<ADD>` elements that have a qualifier equal to `ST`...?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="GRP">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select ="./ADD[QUALIFIER='ST']">
      <xsl:if test="./CONTACT/QUALIFIER='EM'">
        <CONTACT_EMAIL>
          <xsl:value-of select="CONTACT[QUALIFIER='EM']/NUMBER"/>
        </CONTACT_EMAIL>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!--copy all other nodes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Result:

```html
<TEST>
  <CNT>
      <GRP>
         <CONTACT_EMAIL>test@test.de</CONTACT_EMAIL>
         <ADD>
            <QUALIFIER>DP</QUALIFIER>
            <PARTY_NAME_1>Vorname Nachname</PARTY_NAME_1>
            <STREET_1>Strasse 1</STREET_1>
            <CITY>Ort</CITY>
            <POSTAL_CODE>12345</POSTAL_CODE>
            <COUNTRY_CODE>DE</COUNTRY_CODE>
            <CONTACT>
               <QUALIFIER>TE</QUALIFIER>
               <NUMBER>4657</NUMBER>
            </CONTACT>
            <CONTACT>
               <QUALIFIER>EM</QUALIFIER>
               <NUMBER>test2@test.de</NUMBER>
            </CONTACT>
         </ADD>
         <ADD>
            <QUALIFIER>ST</QUALIFIER>
            <PARTY_NAME_1>Vorname Nachname</PARTY_NAME_1>
            <STREET_1>Strasse 1</STREET_1>
            <CITY>Ort</CITY>
            <POSTAL_CODE>12345</POSTAL_CODE>
            <COUNTRY_CODE>DE</COUNTRY_CODE>
            <CONTACT>
               <QUALIFIER>TE</QUALIFIER>
               <NUMBER>12345</NUMBER>
            </CONTACT>
            <CONTACT>
               <QUALIFIER>EM</QUALIFIER>
               <NUMBER>test@test.de</NUMBER>
            </CONTACT>
         </ADD>
      </GRP>
  </CNT>
</TEST>
```

Comment: thats the solution

Comment: Is it? Check your result.

Comment: yes, it is. 
<TEST>
  <CNT>
      <GRP>
         <CONTACT_EMAIL>test@test.de</CONTACT_EMAIL>
         <ADD>...